# int no = Int32.Parse(s1);

Tags: c#

error in this line when i give the string value more than 10 numbers is shows overflow exception??
done in visual studio
entire code as follows

```
string s1 = s.ToString();

int no = Int32.Parse(s1);
int r = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <s1.Length; i++)
{
    r = no % 10;
    sum = sum + r;
    no = no / 10;
}
```

Comment: try  Int64.Parse(s1);

Comment: Just use `long.Parse(s1)`, you need to check against `int.MaxValue` before doing conversion.

Comment: thnkx but if long is used i cant do % operation to it here my logic goes useless so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you like your current data types, you'll need some validation.

Cast to decimal first then check range.

```
decimal d;
bool ok = decimal.TryParse(s.ToString(), out d);
if (!ok) throw new FormatException("Blah blah");
if (d > Int32.MaxValue || d < Int32.MinValue) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Blah blah");
int no = Convert.ToInt32(d);
```